# Making a div on the fly that is resizable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a function that creates a div on the fly using jquery, and the user can define several properties to style the div. The problem is that I want the div to be resizable but the resulting div is the size the user defines but I am not able to resize it.

this is my function:

```
function createDiv(id, divWidth, divHeight, divContent, divBgColor, opacity){
    //FIRST HEX TO RGB FOR BG COLOR & OPACITY
    var currentColor = hexToRgb(divBgColor);
    //CREATE THE WRAPPER DIV
    var wrapper = $('<div/>', {
        id: id
    }).css({
        "backgroundColor": 'rgba('+currentColor+' '+opacity+')',
        "min-width": divWidth,
        "min-height": divHeight
    }).resizable({
        containment: 'parent',
        minHeight: divHeight,
        minWidth: divWidth
        }).appendTo('.current-layer');
}
```

This is the call to the function:

```
onclick="createDiv('1', '200px', '100px', 'text', '#FF0000', 0.5)"
```

I hope someone can tell me what I am doing wrong! TIA

Comment: When do you append to the div to the DOM?

Comment: could you do a jsfiddle?

Comment: Which arguments do you pass to the function? Do you include the jquery-ui-library? Do you receive any errors? How do you append the div to the DOM(the function doesn't return anything, seems to be impossible to use wrapper outside the function)

Comment: why call resizeable when it's not in the DOM. It has no parent when not in DOM to act as containment, or get position and width values from

Comment: I have updated my code. I left out the appendTo command by accident and posted my call to the function. Yes jquery-ui is included. Everything works except for the resize.

Comment: charliefti it is not in the DOM becuase I am trying to create a general function that can be re-used. I may be going about this the wrong way and would really appreciate suggestions as how to do this correctly

Comment: jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SAYVD/  in the jsFiddle the resize width seems to work but the resize height doesnt??

Answer (score 1):

The parent(`containment`) must have a width/height higher than the min-width/min-height of the resizable.
Currently width and height is not set, so it will be 100% and 0

Result: you can resize the resizable:

- **width:** 200px up to the width of the containment(100%)
- **height:** 100px up to height of the containment(also 100px, derived from it's content), so the height is unresizable

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/VnCHA/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem and feel like bit of a muppet.
Because the div was created on the fly I had to make it resizable **after** it was appended to the DOM.